# Plotting in Mathematica

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematica

I'm new to mathematica. How would I plot the following functions in the polar complex plane?

$$ \phi={-k\over 2\pi r}\cos(\theta_0-\theta)  $$

and

$$ \psi={-k\over 2\pi r}\sin(\theta_0-\theta) $$

Please provide the function calls if possible. I realize that I need to pick values for $k$ and $\theta_0$.  It would be even better if someone knew how to sketch the flow.

Comment: Did you try asking here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: No I will try that. Thank you.